# Why don't work my function xmlParser(). Help me please

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello everybody. I have a problem with my code. I use the jquery framework. When I want to call $.ajax(requestOptions), function xmlParser(xml) don't working.**
I try to find a resolve this problem, but I can't nothing find.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var requestOptions = {
    type: "GET", //The method 
    url: "Course_Valute_02-07-2014.xml", //It is reference on xml file
    dataType: "xml", //The type of data
    crossDomain: true, //Allow to do the cross-domain request
    success: xmlParser //Calling function
  };

  function xmlParser(xml) {   
    $("#load").fadeOut();  
    $(xml).find("Valute").each(function() {
      $("#outputListValutes").append(
        "<option value=" + $(this).find("CharCode").text() + ">" + $(this).find("CharCode").text() + "</option>");
    });     
  };

  $.ajax(requestOptions);

  $("#clear").click(function() {
    var sumValue = document.getElementById("sum").value = "";
    var resValue = document.getElementById("result").value = "";
  });

  $("#convert").click(function(xml) {
    //var selectCurrency = $("#inputListCurrency").val();
    //findData(xml);
  }(requestOptions));

  function findData(xml) {

    var decimalOnly = /^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;

    try{

      var shortName = $("#outputListCurrency").val();                                               
      var value = $("#sum").val();

      if(value == "") throw new Error("Empty value");
        else if(!decimalOnly.test(value)) throw new Error("value must be of decimal digits");
          else if(value < 0) throw new Error("Value isn't to be below zero");
            else if(isNaN(parseFloat(value))) throw new Error("Value isn't to be as symbols");

      $(xml).find("Valute").each(function() {                                                           
        if(shortName == $(this).find("CharCode").text()) {

          var nominal = $(this).find("Nominal").text();
          var course = $(this).find("Value").text();    
          var result = parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(nominal) / parseFloat(course);                                    

          document.getElementById("result").value = Number(result).toFixed(2);
        }
      });
    }
    catch(e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the success parameter of the request to use the xmlParser function (forgot () ):

```
var requestOptions = {
    type: "GET", //The method 
    url: "Course_Valute_02-07-2014.xml", //It is reference on xml file
    dataType: "xml", //The type of data
    crossDomain: true, //Allow to do the cross-domain request
    success: xmlParser(data) //Calling function
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution this promlem. I am happy.

```
var courseFilePath = "xml/Course_Currency_02-07-2014.xml";
var listCurrency = [];

function insertOptions(){
    for (var i = 0; i < listCurrency.length; ++i){
        $("#outputListCurrency").append(
        "<option value=" + listCurrency[i] + ">" + listCurrency[i] + "</option>");
    }
}

function xmlParser(xml){

    $("#load").fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("Valute").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).find("CharCode").text();
        listCurrency.push(value);   
    });

    listCurrency.sort();

};

function findData(xml){

    var decimalOnly = /^\s*-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;

    try {

        var shortName = $("#outputListCurrency").val();
        var value = $("#sum").val();

        if (value == "") throw new Error("Empty value");
            else if (!decimalOnly.test(value)) throw new Error("value must be of decimal digits");
            else if (value < 0) throw new Error("Value isn't to be below zero");
            else if (isNaN(parseFloat(value))) throw new Error("Value isn't to be as symbols");

        $(xml).find("Valute").each(function(){
            if (shortName == $(this).find("CharCode").text()){

                var nominal = $(this).find("Nominal").text();
                var course = $(this).find("Value").text();
                var result = parseFloat(value) * parseFloat(nominal) / parseFloat(course);

                document.getElementById("result").value = Number(result).toFixed(2);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e){
        alert(e);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({    
    type: "GET", //The method of sending for data
    url: courseFilePath, //It is reference on xml file
    dataType: "xml", //The type of data
    success: function(xml){
            xmlParser(xml);
            insertOptions();
        }
  });   

    //insertOptions();
  $("#clear").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("sum").value = "";
    document.getElementById("result").value = "";
  });

  $("#convert").click(function() {
    var selectCurrency = $("#inputListCurrency").val();
    $.get(courseFilePath, findData, "xml");
  });
});
```